# unable to solve maths formula in php maths due to e^

Tags: php

I using this formula in PHP but unfortunately, I think it's not working due to the e^ caret symbol how can I use this formula in PHP

```
$risk =100 / (1+ e^(-1 * ((0.028 * 25)+(0.661 * 0)+(0.412 * 0)+(0.079 * 150)+(0.018 * 150)-(0.039 * 150) + (0.07 * 25.96)+(0.481 * 0) - 13.415)));
```

the correct answer will be 10% in the normal calculation.

Comment: Is [`exp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exp.php) what your after (maths is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using exp() function

```
$risk = 100 / (1 +   exp(-1 * ((0.028 * 25) + (0.661 * 0) + (0.412 * 0) + (0.079 * 150) + (0.018 * 150) - (0.039 * 150) + (0.07 * 25.96) + (0.481 * 0) - 13.415)));
```

It gives value 9.994822387895

When substituting e = 2.718281828459045

```
$risk = 100 / (1 +   2.718281828459045**(-1 * ((0.028 * 25) + (0.661 * 0) + (0.412 * 0) + (0.079 * 150) + (0.018 * 150) - (0.039 * 150) + (0.07 * 25.96) + (0.481 * 0) - 13.415)));
```

We get 9.994822387895

Comment: Did you try this yourself? What do you think happens?

Comment: Getting this error while using above  method :  Warning: Use of undefined constant e - assumed 'e' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\health\diabetes-test-risk-assessment.php on line 188
getting this error while using above formula
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\health\diabetes-test-risk-assessment.php on line 188
100

Comment: @AaftabAalamAnsari Use `exp()` as suggested in the comments. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i had use exp() but getting same error and answer also wrong

Comment: will replacing the value of e solve the error? try giving the numerical value of e as 2.71828

Comment: while I am putting this value 2.71828 there is no error but not getting the correct answer

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH  athiradivakar ITS WORKING $risk = 100 / (1 +   2.718281828459045**(-1 * ((0.028 * 25) + (0.661 * 0) + (0.412 * 0) + (0.079 * 150) + (0.018 * 150) - (0.039 * 150) + (0.07 * 25.96) + (0.481 * 0) - 13.415)));